# Visual Studio's icon doesn't seem normal

Tags: visual-studio, icons, shortcut-file

[visual studio icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2G5P.png)
(look at the bottom part of this icon)

I have tried to change the icon and then changed it back, but it doesn't work.
And [the actual visual studio exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKpA5.png) looks quite normal. However when i create a shortcut of this exe, icon seems to be not normal.

So I want to know how to solve this problems and what caused this.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: That's what it's supposed to look like. The small icon and large icon are different, they are not the same icon scaled up and down.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Helps a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an intentional design decision made by the Visual Studio team at the request of the community, believe it or not (see this [completed UserVoice request](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/8958106-change-icon-for-visual-studio-2015)), since it is common that developers have multiple versions of Visual Studio installed and it was causing confusion since the original VS2015 icon was identical to the VS2013 icon.

On the other hand, you should still be able to change your desktop icon as always.  Perhaps what you are seeing is what they mentioned in [these instructions at TenForums](http://www.tenforums.com/customization/15861-change-taskbar-icons-pinned-programs.html) where they mention that it may take a while for the changes to become visible.

I believe that delay can actually be avoided, though, by rebuilding the icon cache according to [these instructions, also on TenForums](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5645-icon-cache-rebuild-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Exiting, isn't it?  Nice digging.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks!  It didn't actually take too much digging.  I remembered it being mentioned in the Update 1 release notes (partly because I don't love the icon either) and the UserVoice link was the first search result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering the question! Now I know why the icon looks that way now. Your answer really helps a lot!